# How do I efficiently select only specific keys from a hasMany collection in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've seen similar questions about collections, but they don't quite fit my use case for a *hasMany* relationship

**Context**: In Laravel 8, via an api controller method, I'm trying to return Account->doctors:hasMany|Doctors with only three key value pairs rather than the entire model.

**The goal** is to make queries as efficient as possible via native laravel methods while keeping the api responses light.

**What I've tried**:

- [`collection->pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) only allows for one key, or a single key, value pair
- I've seen `select` suggested for similar problems, but it doesn't apply to collections

**My current solution** uses `collection->map(model->only(['keys']))`

[`only`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-only) seems to be the weapon of choice for returning select key value pairs from a model, but `only` works [differently on collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-only). In a collection, `only` seems to focus on *which models* to return, rather than *which keys*.

Calling `map` and then running `only` on the individual models does work, but it feels too verbose and makes me think I'm missing a (hopefully) more efficient native method elsewhere.

I don't know how eloquent handles it's queries, but from the syntax I'm using below it appears that `map` requires the full models to be queried before they can be changed and is therefor inefficient, but I realize I could be wrong about that.

```php
return $account->doctors->map(function ($doctor) {
    return $doctor->only(['ref_id', 'name', 'code']);
});
```

Is there a better method in this circumstance that can reduce syntax and increase the efficiency of the query?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map` as a [High Order](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages) function to make the syntax less verbose.

```php
return $account->doctors->map(function ($doctor) {
    return $doctor->only(['ref_id', 'name', 'code']);
});
```

becomes

```php
return $account->doctors->map->only(['ref_id', 'name', 'code']);
```

---

This will **not** change the SQL query itself (`SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE ...`). If you want to change that part, you'll need to change the syntax or pass a Closure where you eager load the relationship.

```php
$account = Account::with('doctors:ref_id,name,code,account_id')->find($id);
$account = Account::with(['doctors' => function ($query) { $query->select('ref_id', 'name', 'code', 'account_id'); }])->find($id);
$account = Account::with(['doctors' => fn ($query) => $query->select('ref_id', 'name', 'code', 'account_id')])->find($id);

$account->load('doctors:ref_id,name,code,account_id');
$account->load(['doctors' => function ($query) { $query->select('ref_id', 'name', 'code', 'account_id'); }]);
$account->load(['doctors' => fn ($query) => $query->select('ref_id', 'name', 'code', 'account_id')]);
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I've understood from your question, you can make use of eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Assuming you've instantiated a hasMany relationship function named doctors in Account Model, you can try something like this:

```
Account::with('doctors:id,ref_id,name,code')->where('your conditions')->get();
```

Keep in mind, you have to include the primary key of doctor (I assumed it is 'id' in this case) when you're trying to execute this.